# Partition Recovery and tools required

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, hardware-failure

I have Windows 7 machine. I had partitioned C: to extended partition D:. Well yesterday I was increasing the space for D: (for installing UBUNTU -dual boot-). I used G-parted of UBUNTU to expand the D:, when I reduced the size of C: and was allocating to D: my system had power failure, now when I turn on the system, D: drive is corrupted. Anyway to recover my files on it? I used R-studio to recover my files but most of files are not recovered( especially pictures), Disk Management show this partition as healthy but display it as RAW.

Answer (score 0):

I would try using the Recuva utility (free version will suffice).  It has helped me on a number of occasions particularly when a client or friend had lost images.

http://www.piriform.com/recuva